# Model selection: lme and splines or gam or gamm?

Tags: lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, splines

I am working with data from a cohort study.

The variables are:

- psychological symptoms (continuous)
- light physcial activity (LPA) (continuous)
- moderate-vigorous physical activity (MVPA) (continuous)
- sedentary behaviour (SED) (continuous)

All data has been collected at 16 different schools (therefore more than 1 level). 
The data is cross-sectional.
My predictor variables are LPA, MVPA, SED.
My outcome variable is psychological symptoms (PS).

Research questions:

1. What is the dose-response relationship between LPA and PS?
2. What is the dose-response relationship between MVPA and PS?
3. What is the dose-response relationship between SED and PS?
4. Does SED moderate the relationship between LPA and PS?
5. Does SED moderate the relationship between MVPA and PS?

My question is: What would you recommend as the first step in my decision for model selection?

Comment: Please can you edit the question and add more detail about the study design. Also, please provide information about *all* the variables (eg scale) . Finally, please explain why you think you need GAM(M) (eg. is it only due to nonlinearites ?)

Comment: @Robert Long: Thank you for your advice. I have edited my question. Pls let me know if it is clearer now. Re Gamm, idd, it is mainly for the non-linearities and the nestedness of data.